# Custom Icons Won't Stay on Right Side of Header when Resized

Tags: css, html, icons, css-float

I have a header which is a bit of a mess. I wanted to have this header based off of the image at full width without changing the height. To achieve this effect, I floated the header image to the left and created a div that filled in the color of the image across the entire page. After doing this, I inserted three images on the right side of the header.

My issue is that when the window is resize, the icons get pushed underneath the header image, also pushing the div with the fill colour below the image. Check out the link to see it right away.

http://jsfiddle.net/theflyingmouse/RaPeG/1/

```
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">

    </div>
    <div class="header-background">

    <div class="new-header">

<a href="http://chrispicco.ca/" rel="home">
<img src="http://chrispicco.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/copy-header-   alter.png" width="1074" height="90" alt="">
</a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Chris-Picco/10992716035">
    <img src="http://chrispicco.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/iconmonstr-facebook-5-                 icon-48-e1382731781591.png"></a>
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/ldrmusicnl">
    <img src="http://chrispicco.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/iconmonstr-youtube-5-  icon-48-e1382731895640.png"></a>
    <a href="mailto:info@chrispicco.ca">
    <img src="http://chrispicco.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/iconmonstr-email-10-icon-       32.png"></a>


    </div></div>






    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h1 class="menu-toggle">Menu</h1>
        <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">Skip to         content</a>

        <div class="menu-main-navigation-container"><ul id="menu-main-        navigation" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-        item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-5"><a href="http://chrispicco.ca/">Home</a>        </li>
    <li id="menu-item-92" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-        page menu-item-92"><a href="http://chrispicco.ca/about/">About</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"><a href="http://chrispicco.ca/music/">Music</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-105" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-105"><a href="http://chrispicco.ca/lyrics/">Lyrics</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-  page menu-item-21"><a href="http://chrispicco.ca/videos/">Videos</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-93" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-  custom menu-item-93"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/ldrmusicnl">Youtube Channel</a>  </li>
    <li id="menu-item-94" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-94"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Chris-Picco/10992716035">Official Facebook Page</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>      
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

</header>
```

And here is some CSS with it...

```
    .header-background {
    background-color: #d8edde;
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    }

    .main-navigation {
    background-color: #d8edde;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px  #ADBEB2;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly. The reason it's dropping is your logo image is bigger then it needs to be (1074px). You could crop it down to only be the required width (about 475px), this would help but it will still drop the icons when the screen gets smaller then that tho.

To force the icons to stay in the top right you can position then absolutely.

Wrap them in a div

HTML

```
<div class="social-container">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Chris-Picco/10992716035">
    <img src="http://chrispicco.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/iconmonstr-facebook-5-icon-48-e1382731781591.png"></a>

    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/ldrmusicnl">
    <img src="http://chrispicco.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/iconmonstr-youtube-5-icon-48-e1382731895640.png"></a>

    <a href="mailto:info@chrispicco.ca">
    <img src="http://chrispicco.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/iconmonstr-email-10-icon-32.png"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.social-container {
  position: absolute;   
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9NRL9/

Answer (score 0):

> use % for all div tag in header

```
#header{
 width:100%;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
```